# Resizing and centring an image within a container

Tags: css

So I have these variable sized images I am trying to fit within a certain container element. I would like to resize the image so 1 side is constrained within the container and the rest of the image is overflowing. I would then like to centre the image.

I made a small visual to show you what I mean:

[image]

Right now I am doing this using a mix of javascript and css. The javascript determines whether it is a horizontal or vertical image and applies a class, then css resizes/moves it accordingly.

I would like to try and do this completely in css if possible. I have a fiddle of some example markup showing you what I mean (note: this markup doesn't have my current javascript solution but I can add it if you would like):

http://jsfiddle.net/cBWq9/2/

For future reference, the example markup is:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x350" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

With some container styling:

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;

    float: left;

    position: relative;

    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 4px;

    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Ideally, the solution would have some sort of generic css styling that resizes the first elements image to have a height of 150px and the second element's image to have a width of 150px. And then centre these images within their respective containers (this centring portion can use css3 so things like translate is fine).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There's a jQuery plugin for that (disclaimer, I wrote it): http://christianvarga.com/jquery-resize-image-to-parent-container-plugin/. It is not possible to do it purely in CSS if you want to use image tags. The CSS only solution is to use background images and `background-size: cover`.

Comment: Unfortunately background-size is not supported in ie8 which I unfortunately still have to cater for. I took a look at your plugin and it seems to solve my problem completely! I have already written a javascript solution for this particular project, but I'll definitely keep your plugin in mind for future projects.